# import svn repository to remote server

Tags: linux, svn

Hi just a quick question here

I got an account on www.assembla.com which is svn repository hosting website.
I managed to checkout/commit to remote repository.

Now I am trying to import my existing local svn rep, to remote server.

I cant use "svnadmin load" since it expecting to find local target not URL.
I tried svn+ssh but it failed to connect.
Among other things I am behind proxy.

my repository is here: https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/xxx/

Do you know how I can import my old repository?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can only import into a *new* SVN repository.

1. Click the **Admin** tab.
2. Click **Tools**.
3. For *Repositories > Source/SVN*, click the **Add** button.
4. Click the new **Source/SVN** tab that appears at the top. If you already have an existing SVN repository, the new tab's name would be appended with "2" or the next available number (e.g., "**Source/SVN2**").
5. Click **Import/Export**.

The Import screen (as shown below) is self-explanatory. Hope it works for you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[How can I import or export a subversion repository?](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/breakoutdocs/FAQ#importexport)

> How can I import or export a
>   subversion repository? Trac tickets?
>   You can find forms for importing and
>   exporting svn repositories in Trac. 
>   Go to your Trac and log in as a space
>   owner. You will see an Admin tab on
>   the top right.  Select Admin, and
>   select “Data Import/Export” from the
>   left menu. There is a link to export
>   the svn repository, and a form to
>   upload a zipped Subversion repository
>   dump. There are also forms for
>   uploading and exporting trac
>   directories. We currently use trac
>   0.10.4.